# Can not decode json string in command line

Tags: json, bash, perl

I have a json that is an array of objects.
The following code works just fine:

```
use JSON qw( decode_json );  
# the contents of json are from the file jsonfile.json  
my $data='[{...}]'; # omitted for clarity    
@decoded = @{decode_json($data)};  
print Dumper \@decoded;
```

But when I try to run it from the command line as an one-liner it breaks

None of the following work:

```
cat jsonfile.json | perl -MData::Dumper -MJSON=decode_json -ne'my $data=q{$_}; print decode_json($data)' 




cat jsonfile.json | perl -MData::Dumper -MJSON=decode_json -ne"print decode_json('$_')"
```

I think the issue is the quoting. I had the same issue in the script until I replaced `qw` with `’` otherwise it would complaint e.g. if an `@` was in the fields or it was confused with the double quotes of the json fields.

What am I doing wrong here?

Another example:
This breaks:

```
$ echo [{"a":"b"}] |perl -MData::Dumper -MJSON=decode_json -ne'print decode_json($_)'
unexpected end of string while parsing JSON string, at character offset 3 (before ":b}]\n") at -e line 1.
```

But this works:

```
$ echo '[{"a":"b"}]'| perl -MData::Dumper -MJSON=decode_json -ne'print decode_json($_)'
ARRAY(0x7fd8d400b2b8)
```

Comment: There seem to be two separate problems here: how to read the whole JSON file, and how to quote command line parameters. For quoting, it's important what shell you are using. Are you using Bash on Linux?

Comment: @amon: yes bash. I don't have an issue with reading the file. Even if I copy paste to the console the string I get the same issue

Comment: `echo [{"a":"b"}]` outputs `[{a:b}]`. in bash and zsh

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perl's `-n` option "causes Perl to assume the following loop around your program, which makes it iterate over filename arguments somewhat like sed -n or awk:

```
  LINE:
    while (<>) {
    ...     # your program goes here
    }
```

" (source: https://perldoc.perl.org/perlrun.html)

`<>` is perl's input operator, in this case called without a filehandle, so it reads from STDIN. Perl automatically splits the input, the default is to split on line breaks (`\n`). This means, that your expression is executed once per input line. Unless your JSON file contains everything in one line, your code will not work!

Perl's special variable `$/` (aka `$INPUT_RECORD_SEPARATOR`) controls how perl splits multi-line input when reading with `<>`. The default value is `\n`, so that every line is read separately. By setting it to `undef`, perl reads the whole input in one go (regardless if it is single-line or multi-line), giving you the complete content of your file in `$data`.

You also need to remove `-n` from perl's parameters and read manually from STDIN.

```
cat jsonfile.json | perl -MData::Dumper -MJSON=decode_json -e '$/=undef; my $data=<>; print decode_json($data)'
```

`$/=undef;` tells perl not to split the input in separate lines.

`my $data=<>;` reads from STDIN. And as we told perl to not split the input, the whole input (your file's complete content) is stored in `$data`.

As a side node: your code `my $data=q{$_};` does not do what you seem to expect: `q{}` is the equivalent of a single quote (`'`), so `$data` contains the literal string `$_` (a dollar sign followed by an underscore), not the content of the variable `$_`.

Comment: Your code works but I am confused. Is there a way to make this work regarless of multiline and single line input?

Comment: @Jim: I rewrote the explanation. Please check if it is clearer now.

Answer (score 2):

Bash has a number of different quoting modes:

- within single quotes `'...'` nothing is expanded. There are no escapes available. So within such quotes you can use `$variables` without them being expanded as Bash variables. This is desirable for Perl one-liners. But you cannot use single quotes within that string. As a consequence, Perl one-liners should prefer quoting operators such as `q(...)` within the Perl code.
- within double quotes `"..."` variables are expanded, and special characters can be escaped. This is not desirable for Perl one-liners.

Bash has these quoting modes but not strings. You can switch between quoting modes within one word, so the command line parameter `foo"bar"baz'qux'` is equal to `foobarbazqux`.

When we look at your JSON snippets:

- `echo [{"a":"b"}]` is equal to `echo '[{a:b}]'`, because the `"` quotes are  stripped. That is not valid JSON.
- `echo '[{"a":"b"}]'` works as expected, because the double quotes are protected by the single quotes.

Within your Perl oneliners:

- `-ne"print decode_json('$_')"` is a double quoted string. The Bash variable `$_` expands to the last argument of the previous command. So we are actually passing something like the argument `"-neprint decode_json('RANDOM GARBAGE')"`.
- `-ne'my $data=q{$_}; print decode_json($data)'` is escaped correctly, as far as Bash is concerned.

Both your initial Perl one-liners use single quotes around the `$_` variable: `'$_'` and `q{$_}`. Perl does not interpolate variables into single quoted strings, so you were using the literal string `$_`, not the value of the `$_` variable. In these cases no quotes were necessary. If you had to use quotes, double quoted strings like `qq{$_}` would have been preferable.

Putting all of this together, a command like this should work:

```
$ perl -MJSON=decode_json -ne'print decode_json($_)' jsonfile.json
```

But note that this reads the file line by line due to the `-n` flag, i.e. expects one JSON document per line.

Comment: The code does not work even as you describe. The snippet of Jochen Lutz works but I am confused about the differences

Comment: @Jim My answer addresses the Bash quoting problems. As explained above, the `-n` flag reads the input line by line. If something doesn't work, please explain precisely *how* it doesn't work. Jochen Lutz'es code uses correct quoting *and* reads the whole file in one go, rather than line by line. So maybe that was part of your problem after all.

Comment: :I am not sure if this helps. If I copy the contents of json from the script file and do `pbpaste| perl etc` it also fails. The json does have new line characters i.e. it is not a single line but I am not sure how I can update the post to help you so I can understand what I am messing up

Comment: @Jim I think I understand. The problem is not how you are supplying the file to Perl, but how Perl is consuming it – with the `-n` flag it assumes one JSON document Perl line. Jochen Lutz shows how to avoid that: with `local $/; my $data = <>;` the whole input can be loaded at once. That is why his solution works.

Comment: So what does `$/=undef` work? And is `my $data = <>;` something like the input stream?